# Redirect User: Delay + Intermediate page

Tags: users, redirection

I have been trying to get a quick easy way to redirect the user, no matter where they go to the site straight to the user login page. But before I do, I want to redirect them to another page saying some message like "Sorry, you need to be authenticated to view blah blah... you are being redirected to the login page".

I currently have:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 0 && arg(0) != 'user'){
    drupal_goto('user/login');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the goto call you can add
   drupal_set_message( $message, $status);

Its the more straightforward solution, although the message will be displayed inside the login page and there wont be any delay.

Or just change the goto path to a custom... 'user/sorry' page with your message, and something like:

```
 <div onLoad="setTimeout('myRedirect()', 6000)"></div>
```

and a JavaScript function

```
function myRedirect(){ window.location = "user/login"; }
```

Add the standard "if you are not redirected, click here" link in case JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: This is a great idea. I need a quick/simple solution. Thanks a ton @Astrayus